# What is the appropriate way to throttle jobs sent to akka actors when the producers are faster than the consumers?

Tags: akka

Pardon me if this is a basic / well known pattern, but I've been researching and can't find a solution. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms.

I have one producer akka actor, which pumps several small jobs involving about 50 KBytes each.  And I am currently dispatching these jobs to consumer akka actors via a round robin router.

The root of the problem is the producer is much faster than the consumer actors.

I've been rolling my own solutions, adding in wait states and measuring average times of the processes to keep a steady rythm of jobs without blowing up the actor message queues. But this involves some synchronization between the actors and I don't think this is the akka way of doing it....it's not loose, it's a closed loop and has feedback, causing synchronization issues(determining how fast to send messages requires feedback from consumers). And if I don't throttle it, the queues blow up in 2 to 3 minutes.

I assume I'm doing this wrong.

So what's the appropriate pattern / method to use in the case when you have a producer that is faster than the consumer actors? Will I need a middleman, like a message queue or a database?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Have you tried having your producers created only when consumers are created?

Comment: I only have one producer and the problem still happens. It is the throughput from the producer to the consumers which overflows with time. I've tried creating a large nr of consumers, but that just delays the problem, still blows up later on.

Comment: Akka Streams is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Viktor. Reading the "getting started" docs it seems like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/index.html) was created to solve exactly that problem (among other things). Take a look at it, it handles back-pressure between faster/slower stages of such processing pipelines.

It also can integrate well with Actors using Sinks/Sources explained here [Akka Streams: Integrating with Actore](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-actors).

Comment: Thank you. Thanks also to Viktor Klang for his reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Akka Streams is the solution. Thank you Viktor Klang and Konrad 'ktoso' Malawski for your response.
This post might provide you quick help for development point of view.
https://blog.redelastic.com/diving-into-akka-streams-2770b3aeabb0#.z0yoceoox